# Convert promise code from Q to bluebird

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

I'm trying to convert this code from Q to bluebird.

1. Is there an easy way (or tool) to convert to bluebird promises?
2. How can the bluebird version of this function be called?
3. How can I catch exceptions?

```
function run (req, res, filePath) {
    var d = Q.defer();

    var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(filePath, { flags: 'w' });
    req.pipe(writeStream);
    req.on("end", function () {
        console.log("Finish to update data file");
        d.resolve();
    });

    req.on("error", function (err) {
        d.reject(err);
    });

    return d.promise.then(function () {
        res.end("File " + filePath + " saved successfully");
    }).catch(function (err) {
        //handle error
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not see any issues in simply replacing `Q.defer` with promise constructor `new Promise(...)` , apparantly, bluebird [api doc](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#new-promisefunctionfunction-resolve-function-reject-resolver---promise) says there used to be `Promise.defer` but it is deprecated in favor of above.

I do not think any change is calling of method `run` is required, since it still returns a promise. Also, catching exceptions would be same as before either reject handler or `.catch`:

```
var Promise = require("bluebird");
...
run: function (req, res, filePath) {
    var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){            
        var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(fileRelPath, {flags: 'w'});
        req.pipe(writeStream);
        req.on("end", function () {
            console.log("Finish to update data file");
            resolve();
        });

        req.on("error", function (err) {
            reject(err);
        });
    });

    return promise.then(function(){
        res.end("File " + filePath + " saved successfully");
    }).catch(function(err){
        //handle error
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Other than your brain & keyboard, I'm not sure.
2. Like any other function: `run()`. (Note: since you call `res.end` in `run`, it doesn't really make sense to do this, but you can chain another promise off of it with `run().then(() => /* do something */ )`).
3. `.catch(handleError)` or `.then(null, handleError)`.

Here's a solution using ES6 (but it should be easy to adapt it for ES5 environments):

```
import Promise from 'bluebird'

function run (req, res, filePath) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        req.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filePath, { flags: 'w' }))
        req.on('end', resolve)
        req.on('error', reject)
    })
    .then(() => res.end(`File ${ filePath } saved successfully`))
    .catch((err) => { /* do something */ })
}
```

Comment: I've node js application, to use that ES6 code do I need to add additional library ?

Comment: You can use babel.js. However, converting it back to ES5 is a matter of using `function (){}` over `() => {}` and using `var Promise = require('bluebird')`